# MongoDB/pymongo error: The DNS response does not contain an answer to the question ... IN SRV

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, dns

I have a python script running in K8s that's been working fine. Trying to run the code locally within it's docker container and I'm getting the following error when it attempts to connect to MongoDB

`pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: The DNS response does not contain an answer to the question: _mongodb._tcp.cluster_name.abc123.mongodb.net IN SRV`

The connection string
`mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster_name.abc123.mongodb.net` is from the Mongo UI "connect" instructions and I validated this against the secret kept in prod vaults.

When I run
`dig srv _mongodb._tcp.cluster_name.abc123.mongodb.net`

I get 3 answers, 1 for each shard. But I think that's fine.

When I use https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#ANY/ (ANY, not A record) it also returns the above 3 answers. A record returns no answer.

As I understand it, this points to it being an issue with my own router/ISP not being able to resolve the DNS record? Is that so? How do I go about diagnosing this and fixing it so I can run this code locally?

EDIT: running the script outside of docker works. Running it inside the container produces the above situation.

Comment: When you say "Trying to run the code locally within it's docker container", describe what you are doing.